# How to add :after :before on submit button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add :after/:before element on a submit button, but it not working for me.

Actually I need to add swipe(Sweep To Right) transition effect on the button from left to right. Like - https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

```
<input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
```

```
.submitBtn{ position: relative; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: #000; text-align: center; color: #FFF; border: none;}
.submitBtn:after{ content: ''; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: yellow; left: 0; top: 0;}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 3):

Input elements do not support pseudo-elements.

As per the specification:

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as if
> they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element.

What this means is pseudo-elements can only be used on container elements and input elements **cannot contain** other elements and as such cannot support them.

---

**WORKAROUND**

To achieve what you are after you could simply wrap the input in a container:

```css
.submitWrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.submitBtn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="submitWrap">
  <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: You have added the yellow background on "submitWrap" div, but in that way how can I access submit button? also can't find "value" of the button here.

Comment: You will need to include a z-index for positioned elements. See changes above.